# Wii on PC monitor - occasionally blacks out

Tags: nintendo-wii, technical-issues, monitor

I use an ASUS PC monitor (unfortunately I can't remember the model type etc, however it is a LCD monitor with HDMI, DVI and VGA ports, as well as a speaker)

I bought a [Wii/PS3 Cable](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/VGA-Cable-PS3-Wii-/180547379545?pt=AU_Video_Game_Accessories&hash=item2a09766159) in the hopes that I can play the Wii on my montiro - much like I do with my PS3 and 360, for the convenience of having evefrything hooked up to the single screen.

It works fine, with the exception that while I am playing the Wii on the monitor, it occasionally blacks out temporarily. Its as if the monitor goes to sleep briefly while I'm playing my game!

Aside from it being quite rude, it'll also make it quite difficult to play any kind of game that involves consistent action! Currently it hasn't caused too many difficulties because I've only been playing the very early stages of Fragile Dreams, but if I get much further it has the potential to become quite a nightmare, aside from being ridiculously annoying.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do to solve this? It would be much appreciated!

Thanks all!

~~~~~~~~~~ Edit With new information

As asked in the comments, I tested a bit more today...
It does not seem to be affected by whether I'm in a cutscene or in game, watching FMVs or running through menus. In fact, it seems utterly disconnected from gameplay at all!

It also is inconsistent with how long between blackouts. The shortest I experienced was about a minute and a half, the longest was a bit over 5 minutes, between blackouts.

When it blacks out, the screen completely turns black for a few seconds, as if I was switching input channels, then the screen returns to showing me my game. Quite frustrating!

I watched the light on the power button as it blacked out, and there was no change - it was signalling that the monitor was still turned on.

Does this give anyone any ideas? I think it *may* be my monitor thinking that there is no display, and trying to find something on another channel, then giving up and returning to the one I manually selected, but I'm not sure (and can't find an option to try and stop it from thinking!)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Edit 2

I thought it may have been the VGA gender changer dongle thing that came with the cable, so I swapped that out for a longer VGA male to male adapter cable. It seems to have slowed down, but is still causing issues.

This is getting ridiculously frustrating, I'm almost at the point of giving up on the Wii altogether over this! If anyone has had this problem before, or has any ideas on how to solve it, please speak up!

Comment: Is there any pattern to the blackouts? Start or end of cut scenes for example?

Comment: Is is always the same time after which this happens?

Comment: To be completely honest, I haven't noticed any patterns. Sometimes it happens during gameplay, sometimes at the start of cutscenes. I haven't had it happen mid-cutscene yet, though that may be just luck. As far as timing goes, again, I haven't noticed. When I get home from work tonight I'll give it a look and try to time it, see if its consistent.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the cable itself or the contact positions. Try moving the jacks and bending the cable slightly to see if you can spot anything suspicious which might even reproduce the case.

This question appears to be more suited for SuperUser actually, be it gaming related or not, it is basically a technical issue.

Comment: Moving the cable around and such I have not been able to spontaneously reproduce the issue, however it is happening a bit less frequently now... still annoying though! If this question is better placed in SuperUser, could someone move it please?